# Is it possible to return a child class from the constructor of its parent class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, constructor

I know this doesn't work this way, since the constructor of a class is a void:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public ParentClass(int case)
    {
       if(case==1) 
           return new ChildClass1();
       else 
           return new ChildClass2();
    }
}
```

Is there any way of doing this.

Comment: No. What you want is a factory method instead of a constructor.

Comment: Constructors don't return values, so no. You could use a factory/static method of some sort.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of design patterns. [Here's a useful](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns) site that has rundowns and examples of a lot of them, for your reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way but...
It sounds like a factory pattern implemented as static method:

```
class ParentClass
{ 
    // "disable" ctor for public use but 
    // allow for children
    protected ParentClass() { }

    public static ParentClass CreateInstance(int @case)
    {
       if(@case==1) 
           return new ChildClass1();
       else 
           return new ChildClass2();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var parentClass=  ParentClass.CreateInstance(1);
```

Comment: Just personal preference, but the `ParentClass` *could* be `abstract`. Was going to mention the method being static too, but you beat me to that one. ;)

Comment: Yeah missed that but noticed very quickly (sometime demo is useful! :)).

Comment: thank you, that is what I was looking for. I already thought about a static method but I did not know how to disable the parent constructor.